# How to run a specific worker in ManageIQ?

Tags: ruby, manageiq

Sometimes I need to run on specific MIQ worker in foreground. 
`rake evm:start` runs all the workers, but if I need just one, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if you are unsure what workers to work with, you might be able to do the following:

1. run `evm` server normally: `bundle exec rake evm:start` and see what worker types were running: `bundle exec rake evm:status`
2. kill `evm` server: `bundle exec rake evm:stop`
3. start a single worker in the foreground:

`ruby lib/workers/bin/run_single_worker.rb MiqWorkerClassHere`

Comment: Also, you may use Foreman for it: http://talk.manageiq.org/t/running-workers-using-foreman-in-development/2585